# Reset when battery powered device receives USB power

Tags: reset, power-on-reset

Device (microcontroller) is powered by battery or USB, through load sharing circuit.  When no USB, operates on battery.  When USB applied, USB powered.

I want device to reset once when USB power applied.  I've found voltage supervisor IC's but all I've found hold reset low when no power.  This would block device from operating on battery power.  The battery may be in charged or fully discharged state when USB is inserted - either way, reset pulse is desired.  Low cost would be ideal.

Schematic of reset part of circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwVHVT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Load sharing circuit is below.

[image]

Comment: You need to show us all the complete circuit, please. We need to see how USB and battery power U1.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I've added the load sharing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 1-shot monostable pulse generator. Connect the input to the USB input. Connect the output to the reset input of U1.

A cheap way to implement that, though not terribly reliable, is a capacitor in series, followed by an inverter gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWfZ90.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>